# How to create a percentage column by slicing every item with its relative third item?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, data-manipulation, data-wrangling

I have a data frame containing two variables.

```
 df <- data.frame(weight = c(30,30,109,30,309,10,20,20,14),
                     nutrition = c("Yes", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "Yes","No"))
```

I want to create an additional column that calculates the percentage change of the weight by dividing it with the value that is present when nutrition is No. The expected output is as follows

```
# expected output
change_of_weight = c(30/109, 30/109, 109/109, 30/10,309/10,10/10,20/14,20/14,14/14)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a group column which creates a new group when `nutrition = 'No'` and divide `weight` by the `last` value.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(group = lag(cumsum(nutrition == 'No'), default = 0)) %>%
  mutate(new_weight = weight/last(weight)) %>%
  #You can also use
  #mutate(new_weight = weight/weight[nutrition =='No']) %>%
  ungroup() %>% dplyr::select(-group)

# A tibble: 9 x 3
#  weight nutrition new_weight
#   <dbl> <chr>          <dbl>
#1     30 Yes            0.275
#2     30 Yes            0.275
#3    109 No             1    
#4     30 Yes            3    
#5    309 Yes           30.9  
#6     10 No             1    
#7     20 Yes            1.43 
#8     20 Yes            1.43 
#9     14 No             1
```

Comment: there is slight modification to the question. Can the new column be created with only weight column being present in the data frame ? The expected output remains the same.

Comment: @Silent_bliss I think that changes the question completely. Can you ask it as a new question?

Answer (score 2):

We can use `data.table` methods.  Convert the data.frame to 'data.table' (`setDT`), grouped by the `lag` of cumulative sum of logical vector, divide the 'weight' by the `last` value of 'weight' and assign (`:=`) it to new column

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, new_weight := weight/last(weight), 
           .(shift(cumsum(nutrition == "No"), fill = 0))]
df
#   weight nutrition new_weight
#1:     30       Yes  0.2752294
#2:     30       Yes  0.2752294
#3:    109        No  1.0000000
#4:     30       Yes  3.0000000
#5:    309       Yes 30.9000000
#6:     10        No  1.0000000
#7:     20       Yes  1.4285714
#8:     20       Yes  1.4285714
#9:     14        No  1.0000000
```

---

if we don't want to update the original data object and wants only a single column as output

```
setDT(df)[, weight/last(weight), .(shift(cumsum(nutrition == "No"), fill = 0))][, .(weight = V1)]
#       weight
#1:  0.2752294
#2:  0.2752294
#3:  1.0000000
#4:  3.0000000
#5: 30.9000000
#6:  1.0000000
#7:  1.4285714
#8:  1.4285714
#9:  1.0000000
```

Comment: there is slight modification to the question. Can the new column be created with only weight column being present in the data frame ? The expected output remains the same.

Comment: @Silent_bliss You meant there is no 'new_weight', right? In that case `setDT(df)[, weight := as.numeric(weight)][, weight := weight/last(weight), 
           .(shift(cumsum(nutrition == "No"), fill = 0))]`

Comment: Sir I meant there is only weight column and no nutrition column in the original data frame. Can the new_weight column be created in that in case ? The expected output remains the same i.e. new_weight = c(30/109, 30/109, 109/109, 30/10, 309/10,10/10) and so on.

Comment: @Silent_bliss That is more easier. `setDT(df)[, weight/last(weight), .(shift(cumsum(nutrition == "No"), fill = 0))][, .(weight = V1)]`

Comment: @Silent_bliss i updated the solution with a single column